# Mysql Conditional sum

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my sql

```
    SELECT A.item_code,A.description,A.uom, A.open_stock, B.recd_total, C.issue_qty 
FROM    chem_master as A 
        LEFT JOIN ( 
                SELECT item_code,  SUM(recd_qty) as recd_total 
                FROM  chem_receipts 
                GROUP BY item_code) AS B 
            ON A.item_code=B.item_code 
        LEFT JOIN(
                SELECT item_code, sum(iss_qty) as issue_qty 
                FROM chem_issue 
                GROUP BY item_code) as C 
            ON A.item_code=C.item_code 
HAVING (open_stock+recd_total-issue_qty) IS NULL OR (open_stock+recd_total-issue_qty)=0
```

Here, table chem_receipts & chem_issue do not have all the matching records in chem_master. Also, there may be multiple matching records.

I want to show items where stock is 0. There are 300 items in chem_master. But only 15 records in chem_receipts since we had additional purchase only in these 15 items. There are 100 records in chem_issue.

Now in the returned query against items where no additional purchase is made is shown as NULL & the same is the case where an item is never issued.

I understand that adding records of all the items with '0' in quantity in issue and receipt table will solve the issue. But that will not be a better method.

How can I improve this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting smacked by the distinction between numeric `0` and `NULL`. You're very close to the right answer.

If I were you, with 300 items, I'd start with an unfiltered query showing stock for every item.

```
SELECT A.item_code,A.description,A.uom, 
       A.open_stock, 
       IFNULL(B.recd_total,0) recd_total, 
       IFNULL(C.issue_qty,0) issue_qty 
 FROM chem_master as A 
 LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT item_code,  SUM(recd_qty) as recd_total 
            FROM  chem_receipts 
            GROUP BY item_code) AS B 
        ON A.item_code=B.item_code 
 LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT item_code, sum(iss_qty) as issue_qty 
            FROM chem_issue 
            GROUP BY item_code) as C 
        ON A.item_code=C.item_code
```

Notice the `IFNULL()` operations turning the NULL results from your `LEFT JOIN` misses into numeric `0` values.  (`COALESCE()` also works for this.)

Then, use that as a subquery for a main query which does your filtering.

```
SELECT item_code, description, uom,
       open_stock, recd_total, issue_qty,
       open_stock+recd_total-issue_qty in_stock_qty
  FROM (
        SELECT A.item_code,A.description,A.uom, 
               A.open_stock, 
               IFNULL(B.recd_total,0) recd_total, 
               IFNULL(C.issue_qty,0) issue_qty 
         FROM chem_master as A 
         LEFT JOIN ( 
                    SELECT item_code,  SUM(recd_qty) as recd_total 
                      FROM  chem_receipts 
                  GROUP BY item_code) AS B 
               ON A.item_code=B.item_code 
         LEFT JOIN(
                    SELECT item_code, sum(iss_qty) as issue_qty 
                      FROM chem_issue 
                  GROUP BY item_code) as C 
                ON A.item_code=C.item_code 
) DETAIL
WHERE (open_stock+recd_total-issue_qty) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Jones...this is what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT A.item_code, A.description, A.uom, A.open_stock,
       COALESCE(B.recd_total, 0) as recd_total,
       COALESCE(C.issue_qty, 0) as issue_qty
FROM . . .
```